# Using JavaScript objects and AJAX vs ASP MVC3 Model

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Since I am fairly new to MVC, I am a little confused as to what is the proper/preferred way of using MVC's Models together with JavaScript objects and AJAX.

As an example, I have an application that displays a calendar with user's events, which are stored in the database. On top of that, these events can be manipulated by moving them around the calendar and then the new times are saved in the database.

When the user first makes a call to my `Calendar` action, I load the events from the database and then pass them to the view via the `CalendarModel`. This allows me to prepare these events visually but now I also need these events to be available as JavaScript objects because I will use AJAX calls to my `UpdateEventTimes` action to persist user's changes.

So my options today are to either "extract" the events' data from the `CalendarModel` and "hardcode" them as a string in JavaScript code or perform an AJAX call from JavaScript to retrieve these events again. Needless to say, I like neither approach so I am wondering if there is some MVC trickery that I am missing that's more *elegant*?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't any. The only option to archive your scenario is to build js from Model like this:

```
<script>
  var events = @(Model.Events.Aggregate(<aggregation function here to build js object>)) ;
</script>
```